# Currency format in dart

Tags: formatting, dart

In C# I can do:

```
12341.4.ToString("##,#0.00")
```

and the result is 12,345.40

What's the equivalent in dart?

Comment: this may help https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_money_formatter#-readme-tab-

Comment: This worked for me, including the Platform.localeName - have a look https://stackoverflow.com/a/63955746/11865941

Answer (score 139):

I wanted to find the solution also, and found that it is now implemented as per following example.

```dart
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

final oCcy = new NumberFormat("#,##0.00", "en_US");

void main () {

  print("Eg. 1: ${oCcy.format(123456789.75)}");
  print("Eg. 2: ${oCcy.format(.7)}");
  print("Eg. 3: ${oCcy.format(12345678975/100)}");
  print("Eg. 4: ${oCcy.format(int.parse('12345678975')/100)}");
  print("Eg. 5: ${oCcy.format(double.parse('123456789.75'))}");

/* Output :  

Eg. 1: 123,456,789.75
Eg. 2: 0.70
Eg. 3: 123,456,789.75
Eg. 4: 123,456,789.75
Eg. 5: 123,456,789.75


 pubspec.yaml :

  name: testCcy002
  version: 0.0.1
  author: BOH
  description: Test Currency Format from intl.
  dev_dependencies:
    intl: any

   Run pub install to install "intl"  
*/
}
```

Comment: This works a treat, even better than the also-available `NumberFormat.currencyPattern()` formatter.

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer how can i set this number format with currency symbol for "it-IT".

Comment: Here is the [document link](https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/NumberFormat-class.html)

Comment: @orlade But it should fail when the currency decimal separator is different from the normal decimal separator. You want to use the `simpleCurrency()` function to get the correct formatting for any locale for sure.

Comment: the round in this function is wrong i tried this oCcy.format(123456789.725) and the resualt was 123 456 789,72

Comment: working bro i change a bit   NumberFormat("#,#00.00"). i want output 00.00

Answer (score 47):

Here's an example from a flutter implementation:

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

final formatCurrency = new NumberFormat.simpleCurrency();

new Expanded(
            child: new Center(
                child: new Text('${formatCurrency.format(_moneyCounter)}',
                  style: new TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.greenAccent,
                    fontSize: 46.9,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w800)))),
```

Results in $#,###.## or $4,100.00 for example.

Note that the $ in Text('${... is only to reference the variable _moneyCounter inside the ' ' and has nothing to do with the $ added to the formatted result.

Comment: how to do it for INR?

Comment: is _moneyCounter a double?

Comment: @LOG_TAG you can use 
 
NumberFormat.simpleCurrency(locale: 'HI', decimalDigits: 0, name: 'INR').format(1000)

output: INR1,000

Answer (score 24):

If you don't wanna print currency symbol:

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

var noSimbolInUSFormat = new NumberFormat.currency(locale: "en_US",
      symbol: "");
```

Comment: what the different of this NumberFormat("#,##0.00", "en_US"); with yours

Comment: for any spanish who sees this:

 var formatter = new NumberFormat.currency(locale: "es_ES", symbol: "");

Answer (score 10):

I'm the author of the dart package money2

https://pub.dev/packages/money2

The package supports fixed precision maths, formatting and parsing of money.

```dart
import 'money2.dart';

Currency usdCurrency = Currency.create('USD', 2);

// Create money from an int.
Money costPrice = Money.fromInt(1000, usdCurrency);
print(costPrice.toString());
  > $10.00

final taxInclusive = costPrice * 1.1;
print(taxInclusive.toString())
  > $11.00

print(taxInclusive.format('SCC #.00'));
  > $US 11.00

// Create money from an String using the `Currency` instance.
Money parsed = usdCurrency.parse(r'$10.00');
print(parsed.format('SCCC 0.0'));
  > $USD 10.00

// Create money from an int which contains the MajorUnit (e.g dollars)
Money buyPrice = Money.from(10);
print(buyPrice.toString());
  > $10.00

// Create money from a double which contains Major and Minor units (e.g. dollars and cents)
// We don't recommend transporting money as a double as you will get rounding errors.
Money sellPrice = Money.from(10.50);
print(sellPrice.toString());
  > $10.50
```

Comment: Beautiful package Brett, thanks for the creation and sharing. This is exactly what I was looking for! Nice documentation too.

Answer (score 6):

```
var number = 10000;

final NumberFormat usCurrency = NumberFormat('#,##0', 'en_US');

print(' \$${usCurrency.format(number))}');
```

-- `$10,000`

if you want to write the cent at the end of the number:

```
final NumberFormat usCurrency = NumberFormat('#,##0.00', 'en_US');
```

-- `$10,000.00`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 5):

I use it. it's working for me

```
class MoneyFormat {
 String price;

 String moneyFormat(String price) {
  if (price.length > 2) {
  var value = price;
  value = value.replaceAll(RegExp(r'\D'), '');
  value = value.replaceAll(RegExp(r'\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))'), ',');
  return value;
  }
 }
}
```

and in TextFormField

```
onChanged: (text) {
 priceController.text = moneyFormat.moneyFormat(priceController.text);
}
```

Comment: Honestly, i dont understand how the regular expression works. I have a string called price = '2845000.00'. How can I convert this to 28,45,000? the above code gives me 28,450,000. Will greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: Wrong regular expressions. This mess up with decimal points.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @Richard Morgan (answer [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50899650/2279390))

This was my final solution.

**Note**: You need the two packages for you to use other currencies.
Also, check what type of data you using for the amount to decide if you want to use `int` instead of `String`. If `int` then no need to use `int.parse()` in the `format()`

> To easily check  `print(amount.runtimeType);`

```
    //packages
    import 'dart:io';
    import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

    final formatCurrency = NumberFormat.simpleCurrency(
          locale: Platform.localeName, name: 'NGN');
    
    final int amount;
   // or final String amount; if gotten from json file 
   // check what type of data with - print(data.runtimeType);

   //generate your constructors for final fields
   Text(
         '${formatCurrency.format(amount)}',
          // or for String '${formatCurrency.format(int.parse(amount))}' 
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 16,
            ),
       ),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

extension DoubleExt on double {
  String toEuro() {
    return NumberFormat.simpleCurrency(
      name: 'EUR',
    ).format(this / 100);
  }

  String toPln() {
    return NumberFormat.simpleCurrency(
      name: 'PLN',
    ).format(this / 100);
  }
}
```

just use it on your double. `1000.0.toEuro()` => `€10.00`

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

final oCcy = NumberFormat.currency(
  locale: 'eu',
  customPattern: '#,### \u00a4',
  symbol: 'FCFA',
  decimalDigits: 2);

print(oCcy.format(12345)) // 12.345,00 FCFA
```