# How to format an interpolated String

Tags: dart, flutter

I need to format a string like `"Send %d seconds ago"`, `"Harry likes %s", "I think %1$s likes %2$s"`. These can be implemented in Android, but i don't know how to implement it in Dart for Flutter.

Answer (score 73):

Dart supports string interpolation

```
var seconds = 5;
print("Send $seconds seconds ago");

var harryLikes = 'Silvia';
var otherName = 'Erik';
var otherLikes = 'Chess';
print("Harry like $harryLikes");
print("I think $otherName like $otherLikes");
```

Also more complex expressions can be embedded with `${...}`

```
print('Calc 3 + 5 = ${3 + 5}');
```

The number types and the `intl` package provide more methods to format numbers and dates.

See for example:

- https://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/intl/latest/intl/NumberFormat-class.html
- [Currency format in dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14865568/currency-format-in-dart?rq=1)

Comment: However, this is not what the author of the question asked for. Strings pulled from *other sources*, like a server, can contain *wildcards* and in *Android* (what was asked) `String.format(stringWithWildcards, one, two, three)` works. How would you do that in *Dart*?

Comment: I'm not sure the question is meant as you interpret it. You would need to process these format parts yourself, for example using regex to find all such format markers and then format the values accordingly and replace the markers with the results.

Comment: The question asks for string *formatting* and not for *interpolation*. I expected that it was not implemented since I could not find anything, but you know more, so I was not sure.

Comment: I had expected to get a comment from the author of the question if this is not what he was looking for, but that's also not always the case, so who knows :D

Comment: Not sure about the author, but I'm looking for the equivalent of C#'s String.Format (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) in Dart/Flutter, which is not the same as interpolation in the answer. What's the best way to achieve that in Dart/Flutter?

Comment: I don't think there is anything like that. Only partial. You can use string interpolation and format the values in various ways.

Comment: I don't think this is an answer for the question.

Comment: @kuuldor Dart does not provide anything else to format strings.

Comment: The comma between the two string inside the print throw an error

Answer (score 62):

Add the following to your `pubspec.yaml`

```
dependencies:
  sprintf: "^5.0.0"
```

then run **pub install.**

Next, import dart-sprintf:

`import 'package:sprintf/sprintf.dart';`

Example #

```
import 'package:sprintf/sprintf.dart';

void main() {
     double seconds = 5.0;
       String name = 'Dilki';
       List<String> pets = ['Cats', 'Dogs'];

       String sentence1 = sprintf('Sends %2.2f seconds ago.', [seconds]);
       String sentence2 = sprintf('Harry likes %s, I think %s likes %s.', [pets[0], name, pets[1]]);

       print(sentence1);
       print(sentence2);
}
```

Output

`Sends 5.00 seconds ago.`

`Harry likes Cats, I think Dilki likes Dogs.`

Source: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/sprintf

Comment: do we really need a 3rd party package by "unverified uploader" to get string formatting? fucking hell dart

Answer (score 11):

Like already stated, I also use the sprintf package but along with a handy extension of the String class.

So after adding the package dependency `sprintf: "^4.0.0"` to your dependencies list in pubspecs.yaml, create a new Dart-file containing the extension for the Spring class contributing a format method like this:

```
extension StringFormatExtension on String {
  String format(var arguments) => sprintf(this, arguments);
}
```

Now after you import the dart file containing the StringFormatExtension extension, you can type something like:

```
String myFormattedString = 'Hello %s!'.format('world');
```

Feels like in Java (where I come from).

Answer (score 10):

If you want String interpolation similar to Android (`Today is %1$ and tomorrow is %2$`), you can create a top level function, or an extension that can do something similar. In this instance I keep it similar to Android strings as I'm currently porting an Android app (Interpolatation formatting starts with 1 rather than 0)

**Top Level Function**

```
String interpolate(String string, List<String> params) {

  String result = string;
  for (int i = 1; i < params.length + 1; i++) {
    result = result.replaceAll('%${i}\$', params[i-1]);
  }

  return result;
}
```

You can then call `interpolate(STRING_TO_INTERPOLATE, LIST_OF_STRINGS)` and you string would be interpolated.

**Extensions**

You can create an extension function that does something similarish to Android `String.format()`

```
extension StringExtension on String {
    String format(List<String> params) => interpolate(this, params);
}
```

This would then allow you to call `text.format(placeHolders)`

**Testing**

Couple of tests for proof of concent:-

```
test('String.format extension works', () {
    // Given
    const String text = 'Today is %1\$ and tomorrow is %2\$';
    final List<String> placeHolders = List<String>()..add('Monday')..add('Tuesday');
    const String expected = 'Today is Monday and tomorrow is Tuesday';

    // When
    final String actual = text.format(placeHolders);

    // Then
    expect(actual, expected);
  });
```

Comment: Great solution, working like champ!, Instead of `+1` and `-1 `we can also do it like this:
`for (int i = 1; i <= params.length; i++) {
        result = result.replaceAll('%$i\$', params[i - 1]!);
      }`

Answer (score 8):

I did it the old fashioned way

```
String url = "https://server.com/users/:id:/view";
print(url.replaceAll(":id:", "69");
```

Answer (score 3):

you could also have something simple like this:

- Usage

```dart
interpolate('Hello {#}{#}, cool {#}',['world','!','?']);
// Hello world!, cool ?
```

- Function

```dart
  static const needleRegex = r'{#}';
  static const needle = '{#}';
  static final RegExp exp = new RegExp(needleRegex);

  static String interpolate(String string, List l) {
    Iterable<RegExpMatch> matches = exp.allMatches(string);

    assert(l.length == matches.length);

    var i = -1;
    return string.replaceAllMapped(exp, (match) {
      print(match.group(0));
      i = i + 1;
      return '${l[i]}';
    });
  }
```

Answer (score -2):

There is now a package for this which works very similar to Python's `format` function.

https://pub.dev/packages/format

I would argue that typically the better solution is the one presented by @Günter Zöchbauer, but a package like `format` does have its place. I find it most helpful when I want to have mostly pre-canned error messages where a few variables might change.

Here is a usage example:

```
import 'package:format/format.dart';

// Base of string defined BEFORE the "seconds" variable which can be created and subbed in later
const String MESSAGE = 'Send {seconds} seconds ago';

// Define "seconds"
int seconds = 1234;

// Sub in the value of "seconds".  Prints "Send 1234 seconds ago"
print(MESSAGE.format({'seconds': seconds});
```

The accepted answer does not allow for an already created string to have a variable subbed in, and the `format` package does substitution more cleanly than other answers which use `replaceAll` or some equivalent.

Comment: Would love to know why people keep down voting this. This answer meets the criteria for "good answers" on SO by including an example and link, provides a way to perform string interpolation in Dart as requested by the OP, and actually offers an additional benefit that no other answer to this question does in the fact that it can operate on precanned strings with named variables unlike the `sprintf` package. If downvoters truly believe this is a bad answer, please indicate why so it can be improved.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer and not downvoted like this! It is much better than the one having the highest rating!