# Parameterized string variables in Dart

Tags: android, flutter, dart

How can I have a string resource in Dart that I can refer to and replace variables in the string?

In Android, with `strings.xml` we can do this:

```xml
<string name="error_message">Error connecting to “%s”</string>
```

```
my_message = resources.getString(R.string.error_message, "Google")
// Error connecting to Google
```

In Python, we can do this:

```py
print("I am %d years old!" % 10)
# I am 10 years old!
```

I want to do something like this in Dart:

```dart
var a = "My name is $s";
print(a, "Bob");
// My name is Bob
```

I don't want this:

```dart
var b = "World";
a = "Hello $b";
print(a)
// Hello World
```

Comment: You could write your own parser or look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51039602/how-to-format-an-interploated-string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Flutter counterpart to `strings.xml` in Android development is the [`intl` package](https://pub.dev/packages/intl). It serves the same purpose of offering an ability to internationalize apps. However, you do *not* have to use it for internationalization, the same way you do not have to translate `strings.xml`.

### `intl`

The way you can define a message is the following:

```dart
class ParameterizedStrings {

  String errorMessage(String name) => Intl.message(
      'Error connecting to $name',
      args: [name]);
}
```

You can [learn more here](https://pub.dev/packages/intl).