# How to put query length into text widget?

Tags: flutter

'''
Text(
FirebaseFirestore.instance
.collection('laundryRequest')
.where("status", isEqualTo: 'waiting')
.where("pickupDate", whereIn: [nextBusinessDay.toString()]).snapshots().length
),
'''

Error:
The argument type 'Future' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.

Answer (score 0):

Let's break your expression down:

```dart
FirebaseFirestore.instance                                      // Returns a FirebaseFirestore
  .collection('laundryRequest')                                 // Returns a CollectionReference
  .where("status", isEqualTo: 'waiting')                        // Returns a Query
  .where("pickupDate", whereIn: [nextBusinessDay.toString()])   // Returns a Query
  .snapshots()                                                  // Returns a Stream<QuerySnapshot>
  .length                                                       // Returns a Future<int>
```

Every time there is a `Future`, you must use `await`, so your code should be instead:

```dart
await FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection('laundryRequest')
  .where("status", isEqualTo: 'waiting')
  .where("pickupDate", whereIn: [nextBusinessDay.toString()])
  .snapshots()
  .length
```

Note that, to use `await`, you must be in a `async` context.

You may want to extract this to a variable, say `length`:

```dart
final int length = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection('laundryRequest')
  .where("status", isEqualTo: 'waiting')
  .where("pickupDate", whereIn: [nextBusinessDay.toString()])
  .snapshots()
  .length;
```

To use it in a `Text` widget, you can use [string formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51039687/9997212):

```dart
Text("$length")
```

Comment: `final int length = await FirebaseFirestore.instance`
  ` .collection('laundryRequest')`
  `.where("status", isEqualTo: 'waiting')`
  `.where("pickupDate", whereIn: [nextBusinessDay.toString()])`
  `.snapshots()`
  `.length;`

Where do I Declare this part?

Comment: I don't know what your full code is, so I can't tell you where you can declare it, but probably before creating your `Text` widget. You can update the question including the code.