# Dart - Adding a recurring character to an integer

Tags: dart, integer, int

I'm working with long integers in **dart** and want to know how to add a comma after every three numbers.

Example;

`999999999` would turn into `999,999,999`

I get this information from an online API, so I can't change the int from a local file and follow that pattern, I need to intercept the int before/as it's being displayed.

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14865568/currency-format-in-dart?rq=1 should help

Comment: Thanks Günter, I'm almost there. Using `"${oCcy.format(currency.total_supply)}"`, I'm getting the error: `Class 'String' has no instance getter 'isNegative'` `Receiver: "1732733.0"` `Tried calling: isNegative`

Comment: Sounds like `total_supply` returns a string instead of a number.

Comment: Oh hahaha, I didn’t even see `Class: ‘String`. Thanks for spotting that Günter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at [this stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14865568/currency-format-in-dart?rq=1) I found a way to accomplish this if your variable is a string.

This is what that looks like;

`import 'package:intl/intl.dart';`

`final oCcy = new NumberFormat("#,##0.00", "en_US");`

`"${oCcy.format(yourVar)}",`

Despite this, I was actually dealing with an integer, so using this method left me with an error. This was easily fixed by converting the string into an int.

This is what that looks like;

`"${oCcy.format(double.parse(yourVar))}",`