# How to format number/currency in dart /flutter

Tags: dart

5Need some help to format  number in dart . As an example, I am getting number on the left and would like to format it to the number on right

```
13 =13
13.0 =13
13.50 =13.50
1300.00 =1,300
1350 =1,350
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Currency format in dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14865568/currency-format-in-dart)

Answer (score 0):

You can use intl package

https://pub.dev/packages/intl

```
var f = NumberFormat('###.0#', 'en_US');
  print(f.format(12.345));
    ==> 12.34
```

Comment: thanks but it does not work for some of the cases 13.0 print 13.0 and not 13