# How to get currency and currency symbol in flutter by country code?

Tags: flutter

I'm converting my app from Java(Android) to Flutter(Dart) and I can't find a method to get the currency from context or from a country code.

Code in Java:

```
String country = Locale.getDefault().getCountry();
String currency = Currency.getInstance(new Locale("", country)).getCurrencyCode();
```

Code in Dart:

```
Locale locale = Localizations.localeOf(context);

String country = locale.countryCode;
```

Comment: Maybe this can help [NumberFormat.currency](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat.currency.html)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

[intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) package does the trick

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

void currency() {
    Locale locale = Localizations.localeOf(context);
    var format = NumberFormat.simpleCurrency(locale: locale.toString());
    print("CURRENCY SYMBOL ${format.currencySymbol}"); // $
    print("CURRENCY NAME ${format.currencyName}"); // USD
}
```

Comment: Localizations.localeOf() return the language preference which on most phones it is  en_us, there NumberFormat.simpleCurrency() willl return $ for someone who is not using the dollar

Comment: but what about when we change the app language? I still getting the device language instead

Comment: even in location on a non dollar currency, it still returns dollar. how do i fix it?

Comment: It's frustrating when you find yourself asking the same questions many months ago

Comment: @shababhsiddique 

 Locale locale = Localizations.localeOf(context).split('_').last.toLowerCase();
//this should resolve your use case, what it does, is the local normally returns 
// language code with country code e.g [en_DE] by passing only the DE in //lowercase, it should work.

Comment: You can also use this with the name of the currency following "ISO 4217" so: GBP, EUR,... in uppercase.

Comment: This method is not giving the correct currency name for some countries if you try for example with the String locale of Venezuela ("es_VE"), the method returns "EUR" as currency name, which is wrong...the correct one is "VED"...And this happens with many countries...some answers are correct, but some others are wrong...I tried this with DartPad and on my machine as well (flutter 3.10.6 and dart 3.0.6)...any ideas why some of the answers are wrong with this method?

Comment: @AdamuMuktar only passing us does not work, NumberFormat.simpleCurrency() needs language code as well.

Answer (score 22):

While the accepted answer does work if your app supports the user's locale, it doesn't work if you didn't explicitly add support for the user's locale.

Instead you can use `Platform.localeName` from the `dart:io` package which will take the locale of the device itself.

For Example:

```dart
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'dart:io';

String getCurrency() {
  var format = NumberFormat.simpleCurrency(locale: Platform.localeName);
  return format.currencySymbol;
}
```

Comment: This is what worked for me. Including the Platform.localName

Comment: great because it doesn't need a context

Comment: Doesn't work on web

Answer (score 11):

By default the country symbol is in dollar, to get your local symbol add the name property like this (for Nigeria - Naira):

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'dart:io';

String getCurrency() {
  var format = NumberFormat.simpleCurrency(locale: Platform.localeName, name: 'NGN');
  return format.currencySymbol;
}
```

Comment: also works well as:
var format = NumberFormat.simpleCurrency(name: 'NGN');

Answer (score 9):

after a long time of searching on this problem the only solution that solved my problem is USE A FONT THAT SUPPORT YOUR SYMBOLE.
this was my symbole "₺" and the font that supported it is "Roboto", you can specify a font for your text like this:

```
  Text('₺',
     style: TextStyle(
     fontFamily: 'Roboto',
      )),
```

Comment: Hi, this is not what I asked. I asked if there is a method to get the symbol dynamically based on the current country of the user, not how to view it on my widget. This is more like a Dart question rather than a Flutter question

Answer (score 3):

You can get currency code using [currency_pickers](https://pub.dev/packages/currency_pickers) by giving it user country code.

```
CurrencyPickerUtils.getCountryByIsoCode('PK').currencyCode.toString() // PKR
CurrencyPickerUtils.getCountryByIsoCode('US').currencyCode.toString() // USD
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the country currency symbol using currency_pickers?

Answer (score 3):

This is very easy,
just search the Country symbol on google then add in tin the text widget like this,`Text( "₦20000", style: TextStyle( fontSize: 24.0, fontFamily: '' ), )`

no need to add font family if you are not sure the supported family.

Comment: Should have specified that this only works IF you provide the font family.

Comment: Hi, this is not what I asked. I asked if there is a method to get the symbol dynamically based on the current country of the user, not how to view it on my widget. This is more like a Dart question rather than a Flutter question

Answer (score 0):

NumberFormat.simpleCurrency(locale: locale.toString()) just returns you TL for Turkish currency sign; not the actual currency sign ₺.

Why don't you just right '₺'?

Or you can choose to use  Html(data: '₺'). You have to add flutter_html to pub spec.yaml to use Html

Both will give you what you want ...

Comment: Hi, this is not what I asked. I asked if there is a method to get the symbol dynamically based on the current country of the user, not how to view it on my widget. This is more like a Dart question rather than a Flutter question

Answer (score 0):

Just copy the currency symbol from Google and paste it into your text widget. If it doesn't show well, it is probably your font. Just change the font of that instance or make it a different font. Sometimes I just pass an empty string to the font family. Found out it solves the problem...

Comment: Hi, this is not what I asked. I asked if there is a method to get the symbol dynamically based on the current country of the user, not how to view it on my widget. This is more like a Dart question rather than a Flutter question

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).