# Get currency symbol from currency/country code

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I have my app translated to different languages (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_translate) and I also provide the option to select a specific currency (https://pub.dev/packages/country_currency_pickers):

[image]
*first 2 options*

When I select the currency I get this:

[image]

Now that everything is selected I need to update my currency and for that I can do:

```
NumberFormat.simpleCurrency(
      locale: "en_GB",
).format(money);
```

Notice that I have `en_GB` which is what I'd need here to display pounds. For this example I get `es` from the language and `GB` from the currency but `es_GB` gets euros instead of pounds, which is what I'd need.

- How can I get the country code from any of the previous parameters?
- Can I pass something else to get the symbol like currencyCode for example?

Comment: Check out this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58766133/how-to-get-currency-and-currency-symbol-in-flutter-by-country-code

Comment: I cannot take from Localizations.localeOf(context). That returns "en" because that's what I'm saving, because I only have a en.json for translations. I need to take it from one of the properties I posted

Comment: (In fact I asked myself on that question few months ago [and now again] with no luck)

Comment: I if understand correctly you want the `en_GB` String right? You say you get a String `en` (I assume it is `en` because you wrote `es`) and a String `GB` you can just join them with an underscore and use that right?

Comment: no because as I mentioned I can have es for the language and GB/GBP for the currency. If I use "es_GB" it will take euros when I need pounds

Comment: There should be something to get a currency symbol from a currency code, not only from a country code... but I can't find it. To me that would have more sense

Comment: I see. Have you tried using the 'name' param in the constructor https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat.simpleCurrency.html `If name is specified, the currency with that ISO 4217 name will be used. Otherwise we will use the default currency name for the current locale.` In your case `currencyCode` `GBP`

Comment: Wow, that's perfect, thanks! If you want to provide a final answer the code is NumberFormat.simpleCurrency(
      name: "GBP",
      decimalDigits: 0,
    ).format(money)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use provide `name` in the constructor. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat.simpleCurrency.html

> If name is specified, the currency with that ISO 4217 name will be used. Otherwise we will use the default currency name for the current locale.

```dart
NumberFormat.simpleCurrency(
  name: "GBP", //currencyCode
).format(money)
```

Comment: I tried with pounds and it was working fine but I tried with euros and the format doesn't seem correct in this case. The symbol goes to the left and uses commas instead of dots. This wasn't in the original question anyway but didn't face it until now

Comment: I guess it's not really important since I can use "locale: myLang" here. The situation of having a language with a different currency is not going to be common so if I have everything in Spanish and numbers looks like "450.000,01 £" is not that bad anyway