# Convert String to Currency format in flutter

Tags: flutter

This gives me a string value 200000 which i want to show like this 2,00,000 is there any way to do this in flutter.

```
snapshot.data[index]["price"]
```

Comment: Use this package Flutter Money Formatter
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_money_formatter

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14865568/currency-format-in-dart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
final format = NumberFormat("#,##0.00", "en_US");
String cur= format.format(200000).toString();
```

Comment: final format = NumberFormat("##,##0", "en_US");
                double price = double.parse(snapshot.data[index]["price"]);
                String cur = format.format(price).toString();  this worked for me but how can i get first comma after 3 digits then after every two. Example 2,00,000

Comment: final format = NumberFormat("#,###,##", "en_US");
                double price = double.parse(snapshot.data[index]["price"]);
                String cur = format.format(price).toString();   THIS WORKED.