# How to format numbers as currency strings in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, formatting, currency

How can I convert my below codes to currency Dart/Flutter?

There is a class named number format in flutter, but I could not quite figure it out. Can you please help about the issue.

Example "$ 3,500.00"

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Text(
          "Toplam Masraf: ",
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.orange.shade500,
              fontSize: 15,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
        ),
        Text(
          
            toplam >= 0 ? "${toplam.toStringAsFixed(2)}" : "0.00".toString(),
          
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.orange.shade900,
              fontSize: 20,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w800),
    ),
        Text(
          "₺",
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.orange.shade900,
              fontSize: 25,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w800),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Currency format in dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14865568/currency-format-in-dart)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the `NumberFormat` class will help you: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/NumberFormat-class.html

Did you try the examples?